# Custom CMD commands stored in a single file

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm trying to create my own 'Make' like commands where I can execute commands such as `make clean`, `make install`, `make server`. I have made a make.bat file, where I have stored these commands.

```
@echo off
 clean:
 rmdir node_modules
 install:
 npm install
 server:
 node index.js
```

This method, of course, does not work, and I'm not wanting to install a Makefile program so I can learn more ways to use CMD.

Is it possible to create a batch file to do something like this? Or will I have to install a Makefile program?

Comment: "Is it possible to create a batch file to do something like this?" Yes. But why reinvent the wheel? What's wrong with installing make?

Comment: @DavidPostill I agree that in this instance it is probably a good idea to use make and not reinvent the wheel, but when I was young, I did a very similar project as this and also reinvented the wheel, and it brought my extensive knowledge of batch scripting, a skill still very useful for me today. So what is the gain? experience. :)

Comment: @DavidPostill I am using my USB to save these files. Many computers I will be using the USB to program my 'server' on will be on restricted computers that will not let me install software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do this.

Batchfiles have access to all the parameters that are given after its name. The first 9 are accessible through %1, %2, %3, %4... %9 and you can then use the command `shift` to shift everyting up, getting access to parameters 10 and more.

Now, in your example, only the first parameter is used, but you now know you can actually use other parameters too.

The next step is jumping around in your batch file. You can use the `IF` and `GOTO` commands together with `:labels` to do just that.

An IF statement looks like this:

```
IF "%1"=="clean" GOTO clean
```

You can put all your if statements under eachother.

At the end of the if statements, you put a notice that no valid parameter was entered:

```
echo No parameter or an invalid parameter was used.
echo.
echo Please use make with any of the following parameters
echo    clean      - remove the nod_modules folder.
echo    install    - execute npm install.
... etc.
```

Once you have the help page worked out, you then need to jump to the end. Busines logic suggests to use an END label and jump there, so you can put a command at the end if you need, that will work everywhere, such as pause.

So you would then put a:

```
goto end
```

Now we need to add all the functions.

You start with a label.

```
:clean
```

And then you add your command

```
rmdir node_modules
```

followed by a jump to the end of the script, because we don't want the other commands to be executed as well.

You can even go more fancy and use the 2nd parameter to specify what folder to be removed. For example:

```
rmdir %2
```

You would now run `make clean node_modules` to remove that folder.

```
goto end
```

So your small function looks like this:

```
:clean
rmdir node_modules
goto end
```

After you list all the functions, you obviously have to place an end too:

```
:end
```

Any optional command at the end can be placed afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! Slightly confused how you're telling me to set it up: https://imgur.com/a/LZgJy

Comment: Remove the bottom 3 labels and let the script naturally go there.

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer by checking the check mark, so others know you no longer need help.